# Cursor inside cursor: Alternative?

Tags: sql-server, cursor

So, I have the following problem:

I have 4 tables: Range Information, Range Percentage, DGRange and SGRange

Range information has a 1 - N to Range Percentage ( IE: N percentages to 1 range )

Both DGRange and SGRange connect these two tables to other external fonts.

It shouldn't be that way. But that is the way the system was built, and now I can only fix the problems that appear on that stupid decision.

In any case, we found times that both DGRange and SGRange are pointed to the same primary key when they shouldnt - and as such, once the system changes any information from that range it screws up something else in the system. As such, I must find out every time we have this duplicates ( *very* easy to do ) and duplicate the whole record on RangeInformation/RangePercentage and point one of them to the new record.

My problem is that right now I am thinking of using a cursor inside a cursor, and I believe that there may be a easier way to do it.

Is there a better way?

```
DECLARE @range nvarchar(10) 
DECLARE @rangeinfoid nvarchar(10)
DECLARE @lowerlimit money
DECLARE @Upperlimit money
DECLARE @CurrentYear smallint
DECLARE @Percentage float

DECLARE subgroup_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT distinct a.RangeInformationId
FROM SubgroupRange a, DiscountGroupRange b
where a.RangeInformationId = b.RangeInformationId

DECLARE rangeperc_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT  CurrentYear,
    Percentage
    from RangePercentage 
    where RangeInformationId = @range

OPEN subgroup_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM subgroup_cursor INTO @range  



WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
   select   @rangeinfoid = RangeInformationId , 
            @lowerlimit = LowerLimit, 
            @Upperlimit = UpperLimit
   from RangeInformation 
   where RangeInformationId = @range

   --Add insert here

   OPEN rangeperc_cursor
   FETCH NEXT FROM subgroup_cursor INTO @CurrentYear, @Percentage

   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    print(@CurrentYear)
    print(@Percentage)
    --Add insert here
    FETCH NEXT FROM rangeperc_cursor INTO @CurrentYear, @Percentage
    END


   FETCH NEXT FROM subgroup_cursor INTO @range
END  

CLOSE subgroup_cursor  
DEALLOCATE subgroup_cursor 

CLOSE rangeperc_cursor  
DEALLOCATE rangeperc_cursor
```

Comment: Cursors are pretty resource intensive, especially without indexes built for your keys. Would it be possible to first build a temp table in place of your subgroup_cursor, then build a secondary temp table inside your ranceperc_cursor where the `RangeInformationID IS IN #temp`, executing your inserts based on that?

Comment: This could almost certainly be done as a single insert but without some table structures and data to work with it is difficult to put together. sqlfiddle.com is a great place to start to put together the tables and such.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented above this is difficult to know exactly what you are trying to do but does something like this get you the data you need?

```
select ri.RangeInformationId
    , ri.LowerLimit
    , ri.UpperLimit
from RangeInformation ri
join SubgroupRange sr on sr.RangeInformationId = ri.RangeInformationId
join DiscountGroupRange dgr on dgr.RangeInformationId = sr.RangeInformationId
```

You really should get on the habit of this style of join. It is a little cleaner code wise and helps prevent the accidental cross join by forgetting the join predicates as a where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the comment I left, for clarity.

Essentially, try removing the `subgroup_cursor` altogether by creating the same population in a temp table:

```
DECLARE @rangeinfoid int
DECLARE @CurrentYear smallint
DECLARE @Percentage float



CREATE TABLE #temp_subgroup
(
  RangeInformationID int
)
INSERT INTO #temp_subgroup
(RangeInformationID)
SELECT distinct a.RangeInformationId
FROM SubgroupRange a, DiscountGroupRange b
where a.RangeInformationId = b.RangeInformationId

DECLARE rangeperc_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT  CurrentYear,
    Percentage,
    RangeInformationID
    from RangePercentage 
    where RangeInformationId IN (SELECT RangeInformationID FROM #temp_subgroup)

OPEN rangeperc_cursor 
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> 0)
     BEGIN
       FETCH NEXT FROM rangeperc_cursor INTO @rangeinfoid, @CurrentYear, @Percentage
          CREATE TABLE #temp_rangeupdate
          (
             RangeInformationID int,
             LowerLimit money,
             UpperLimit money
          )
          INSERT INTO #temp_rangeupdate
          ( RangeInformationID, LowerLimit, UpperLimit)
          SELECT RangeInformationID,
                 LowerLimit,
                 UpperLimit
          FROM RangeInformation
          WHERE RangeInformationID = @rangeinfoid



          -- UPDATE/INSERT #temp_rangeupdate
          -- UPDATE/INSERT Production Tables from #temp_rangeupdate

DROP TABLE #temp_rangeupdate

END
DROP TABLE #temp_subgroup
CLOSE rangeperc_cursor
DEALLOCATE rangeperc_cursor
```

Comment: I like dropping the second cursor but the first cursor is not needed either. In this example you are using a cursor to generate a series of insert statements.

Comment: True, I just wasn't sure of the actual Table Structure and didn't want to assume. This way, if OP *must* use a cursor, we've gotten rid of one. Otherwise, I'm sure a simple CTE or direct statement could probably work.